# calculate data for upcoming year in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to python. May someone please please help me what the below code output will be

Code 1.

```
change_qtr_last_day = {datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 30).date(): datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 29).date(),
                datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 30).date(): datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 28).date(),
                datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 31).date(): datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 30).date()}
```

code2:

```
change_qtr_last_day = {datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 30).date(): datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 29).date(),
                datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 30).date(): datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 28).date(),
                datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 31).date(): datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 30).date()}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Why don't you run it to see what the output is?

Comment: Neither of those statements output anything.  If you print change_qtr_last_day, you will get exactly what you typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The output of the first script will be: **

```
{datetime.date(2018, 9, 30): datetime.date(2018, 9, 29), datetime.date(2019, 9, 30): datetime.date(2019, 9, 28), datetime.date(2019, 3, 31): datetime.date(2019, 3, 30)}
```

**Output of the second script will be: **

```
{datetime.date(2019, 9, 30): datetime.date(2019, 9, 29), datetime.date(2020, 9, 30): datetime.date(2020, 9, 28), datetime.date(2020, 3, 31): datetime.date(2021, 3, 30)}
```

*If you are wondering why it isn't only showing the date and is showing the function name, it is because `datetime.datetime().date()` returns a class*

**But if you want to only see the it as a proper date instead of class, use the `str()` function**
Eg:

```
change_qtr_last_day = {str(datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 30).date()): str(datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 29).date())}
```

output:

```
{'2018-09-30': '2018-09-29'}
```